# Fetch random user API

Tags: javascript, async-await, fetch

I'm trying to use the random user API to fetch some data, but seeing a "Failed to fetch" error. Could someone point me in the right direction for how to fix this? TIA :)

```
async function getUsers() {
  let users = await fetch('https://randomuser.me/api/?results=2');
  let data = await users.json();
}

await getUsers();
```

Errors:

```
GET https://randomuser.me/api/?results=5 net::ERR_FAILED
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch
```

Promise:

```
Promise {<pending>}__proto__: Promise
[[PromiseState]]: "rejected"
[[PromiseResult]]: TypeError: Failed to fetch
```

[image: async-await-fetch-fail1]

*UPDATE: it turns out I was testing this in a new tab/blank page, which does not show the full error which was:
"Access to fetch at '...' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled."
I installed a Chrome extension to resolve this for now, although I'm sure there's probably a better/more permanent way to fix this, and I might try that some other day!*

Comment: getUsers() is async, so you should wait for it with await getUsers() or getUsers().then( () => ....)... Don't know if this is the problem, but the promise must be resolved.

Comment: Put a try/catch and print out the error

Comment: I suspect something is going wrong in your fetch, or where you get the json. I would do as the above suggests and wrap it in a try catch and print out the results of your fetch.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use `.then()`

```js
function getUsers() {
    fetch("https://randomuser.me/api/?results=2")
      .then((results) => {
        return results.json();
      })
      .then((data) => {
        console.log(data);
        // Access your data here
      });
  }
  
getUsers();
```

And you could also wrap it all in an async function as await must be used inside an async function:

```js
(async function () {
  const users = await fetch("https://randomuser.me/api/?results=2")
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((data) => {
      return data;
    });

  console.log({ users });
})();
```

OR using your original syntax:

```js
async function getUsers() {
  const users = await fetch("https://randomuser.me/api/?results=2");
  return users.json();
}

getUsers().then((data) => console.log(data));
```

Comment: Same error with this one too unfortunately, but thanks.

Comment: You have access to the resolved promise inside the second `.then()`. It is here that you can assign your data. For instance, if you are using React, you could set your state at this point and access the data outside the function.

Comment: I made some edits and added a couple more options. Let me know if that helps!

Answer (score 1):

You must await your async function to resolve a promise like this.

```
 async function getUsers() {
  let users = await fetch('https://randomuser.me/api/?results=2');
  let data = await users.json();
}

await getUsers();
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried this but unfortunately still running into the same error. I updated my post with more info and a screenshot.