# Fetch randomuser API results

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

It's my first time using the fetch API and I've got myself stuck here. Basically, I structured my code around one of the snippets from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67371374/16968225). I'd like to use the results from one request and populate them into various fields in a form but my current setup seems to be running the request for each field. Here's what I have:

```
async function fetchUsers() {
  let response = await fetch("https://randomuser.me/api/?format=json");
    return response.json();
};

function getInfo() { 
  fetchUsers().then((data) => document.getElementById("c_fname").value = data.results[0].name.first);
  fetchUsers().then((data) => document.getElementById("c_lname").value = data.results[0].name.last);
  fetchUsers().then((data) => document.getElementById("c_phone").value = data.results[0].cell);
}
```

I just can't figure out how to do one request and then drop that response as an object into a new variable. Then I could just easily do something like `document.getElementById("c_phone").value = newVariable.results[0].cell;`.

[Here's the whole thing in context in a CodePen](https://codepen.io/cjglitter/pen/bGMxMPm).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> seems to be running the request for each field

Because you're calling `fetchUsers()` three times, and that function performs that AJAX request.

Just call the function *once* and use the resulting data for the three elements you want to populate:

```
fetchUsers().then((data) => {
  document.getElementById("c_fname").value = data.results[0].name.first;
  document.getElementById("c_lname").value = data.results[0].name.last;
  document.getElementById("c_phone").value = data.results[0].cell;
});
```

There's no rule stating that you can only perform a single operation in the `.then()` callback.  What you're passing to that callback is a function, and that function can contain as much code as you like.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. I tried this already but didn't think to use a curly bracket so it kept failing. Thanks a million for solving this morning's headache for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to get easy user attributes.

```js
const fetchUsers = async() => {
  let response = await fetch('https://randomuser.me/api/?format=json');
  return response.json();
};

fetchUsers().then(({
  results
}) => {
  const [user] = results;
  document.getElementById('c_fname').value = user.name.first;
  document.getElementById('c_lname').value = user.name.last;
  document.getElementById('c_phone').value = user.cell;
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #255E7B;
  color: #47DAC1;
}
.link-alike {
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: #F1D13D;
}
.link-alike:hover {
  color: #fbd422;
}
```

```html
<form action="/checkout_success" method="post" id="hidden_form">
  <input type="hidden" name="nonce" id="nonce" />
  <h3>Payment Total</h3>
  <label for="total">Total</label><br />
  <input type="number" id="total" name="total" value="1.00" onblur="formValidation()" /><br />
  <h3>Customer Info</h3>

  <div class="link-alike" id="randomizer-link" onCLick="getInfo()">
    Random info?
  </div>
  <br />

  <label for="c_name">Name</label><br />
  <input type="text" id="c_fname" name="c_fname" placeholder="First" required size="7" required />
  <input type="text" id="c_lname" name="c_lname" placeholder="Last" required size="7" required /><br />
  <label for="c_phone">Phone</label><br />
  <input type="string" id="c_phone" name="c_phone" /><br />
  <label for="c_street">Street Address</label><br />
  <input type="text" id="c_street" name="c_street" required /><br />
  <label for="c_street2">Address Line 2</label><br />
  <input type="text" id="c_street2" name="c_street2" /><br />
  <label for="c_city">City</label><br />
  <input type="text" id="c_city" name="c_city" required /><br />
  <label for="c_state">State/ Province</label><br />
  <input type="text" id="c_state" name="c_state" required /><br />
  <label for="c_country">Country</label><br /> [PLACEHOLDER]
</form>
```